# Regular expression (regex) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that can validate a string in the following criteria.

- Beginning with the verbatim text ROLE_.
- Only a combination of capital letters and undescores are allowed.
- Must have minimum of 6 and maximum of 20 characters in it.
- Two or more consecutive underscores are disallowed.
- Leading and/or trailing underscores are disallowed.
- The text ROLE_ADMIN is disallowed.

Accordingly, the following regex works in Java.

```
(?!.*__.*)(?!^ROLE_ADMIN$)(?!.*_$)(ROLE_[A-Z_]{1,15})
```

But in JavaScript, a string like `ROLE_ADMIN_s` (`s` at the end in small case) is treated as a valid string that shouldn't actually be. The maximum allowable characters (20) are also not validated correctly.

I'm using the `match()` function like,

```
if($("#txtAuthority").val().match("(?!.*__.*)(?!^ROLE_ADMIN$)(?!.*_$)(ROLE_[A-Z_]{1,15})"))
{
     //...
}
```

Comment: You need to add `^` to the start and `$` to the end. Also, it's not your issue because the browser handles it automatically in this case, but you should wrap regexps in `/myexpression/` instead of `"myexpression"`

Comment: :-) I had reverse trouble while moving from js to java - adding `.*` at start & end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java’s `matches` method expects the pattern to match the whole string while JavaScript’s `match` method is rather a *find any match* method as it suffices that the pattern is found somewhere inside the string.

```
"ROLE_ADMIN_s".match(/(?!.*__.*)(?!^ROLE_ADMIN$)(?!.*_$)(ROLE_[A-Z_]{1,15})/)[0] === "ROLE_ADMIN_"
```

If you want JavaScript’s `match` to act like Java’s `matches`, use anchors for the begin (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string:

```
/^(?!.*__.*)(?!^ROLE_ADMIN$)(?!.*_$)(ROLE_[A-Z_]{1,15})$/
```

This will fail on your string:

```
"ROLE_ADMIN_s".match(/^(?!.*__.*)(?!^ROLE_ADMIN$)(?!.*_$)(ROLE_[A-Z_]{1,15})$/) === null
```

Comment: `/^(?!.*__.*)(?!^ROLE_ADMIN$)(?!.*_$)(ROLE_[A-Z_]{1,15})$/` evaluates to false on valid strings like - `ROLE_ADMIN_S`.

Comment: This works when I remove the forward slash `/` from both sides of the expression like  `^(?!.*__.*)(?!^ROLE_ADMIN$)(?!.*_$)(ROLE_[A-Z_]{1,15})$`. I don't get it correctly.

Comment: @Tiny In JavaScript, [`RegExp` objects have a literal syntax that is `/<pattern>/<flags>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). Of course, if you use those literals as a string, i.e. `"/<pattern>/<flags>"`, the delimiters `/` are also treated as part of the pattern.